# Heroku clojure webapp crashes with error "That's not a task. Use "lein help" to list all tasks.'

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen

I can deploy the sample heroku clojure webapp as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application). However a custom webapp, running fine locally, crashes on access.

*heroku logs*:

```
2013-11-28T02:01:57.142302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-11-28T02:01:57.124843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-11-28T02:02:02.579325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `lein with-profile production trampoline run`
2013-11-28T02:02:03.366402+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2013-11-28T02:02:05.136478+00:00 app[web.1]: That's not a task. Use "lein help" to list all tasks.
2013-11-28T02:02:06.366976+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-11-28T02:02:06.377083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can't see `heroku config` listing `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` either. What am i missing?

*project.clj*:

```
(defproject xxx "0.1.0"
  :warn-on-reflection false
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.3"]
                 [ring "1.2.1"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.6"]
                 [compojure "1.1.6"]
                 [enlive "1.1.4"]
                 [ring/ring-devel "1.1.0"]
                 [ring-basic-authentication "1.0.1"]
                 [com.cemerick/drawbridge "0.0.6" :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.nrepl]]
                 [environ "0.4.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.8"]
            [lein-environ "0.4.0"]]
  :main xxx.web)
```

*web.clj:*

```
(ns xxx.web
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET PUT POST DELETE ANY]]
            [compojure.handler :refer [site]]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [ring.middleware.stacktrace :as trace]
            [ring.middleware.session :as session]
            [ring.middleware.session.cookie :as cookie]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.middleware.basic-authentication :as basic]
            [cemerick.drawbridge :as drawbridge]
            [ring.middleware.params :as params]
            [ring.middleware.keyword-params :as keyword-params]
            [ring.middleware.nested-params :as nested-params]
            [ring.middleware.session :as session]
            [ring.middleware.basic-authentication :as basic]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]
            [xxx.templates :as templates]))


(defn- authenticated? [user pass]
 ;; TODO: heroku config:add REPL_USER=[...] REPL_PASSWORD=[...]
  (= [user pass] [(env :repl-user false) (env :repl-password false)]))

(def ^:private drawbridge
  (-> (drawbridge/ring-handler)
      (session/wrap-session)
      (basic/wrap-basic-authentication authenticated?)))

(defroutes app
  (ANY "/repl" {:as req}
       (drawbridge req))
  (GET "/" []
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
        :body (templates/index "Hello.") })
  (ANY "*" []
       (route/not-found (slurp (io/resource "404.html")))))

(defn wrap-error-page [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (try (handler req)
         (catch Exception e
           {:status 500
            :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
            :body (slurp (io/resource "500.html"))}))))

(def drawbridge-handler
  (-> (cemerick.drawbridge/ring-handler)
      (keyword-params/wrap-keyword-params)
      (nested-params/wrap-nested-params)
      (params/wrap-params)
      (session/wrap-session)))

(defn wrap-drawbridge [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (let [handler (if (= "/repl" (:uri req))
                    (basic/wrap-basic-authentication
                     drawbridge-handler authenticated?)
                    handler)]
      (handler req))))

(defn -main [port]
  (let [port (Integer. (or port (System/getenv "PORT")))]
    ;(jetty/run-jetty #'app {:port port :join? false})))
    (jetty/run-jetty (wrap-drawbridge app) {:port port :join? false})))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using a different version of Leiningen locally than @ Heroku.

From [Heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-support):

> Leiningen 1.7.1 will be used by default, but if you have :min-lein-version "2.0.0" in project.clj (highly recommended) then the latest Leiningen 2.x release will be used instead.